# Mimicking custom function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have defined some custom functions in the following script and attached with my gameobject. I want to declare my function `OnReticleEnter()` to mimick `OnPointerEnter()`. Is it possible? I want this because I want to access my function `OnReticleEnter()` in the inspector so that I can define multiple actions like EventTrigger's Point Enter, Exit etc.
Is it possible to make the function `OnReticleEnter()` to behave as `OnPointerEnter()` programmatically?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
        // Custom reticle events
    public GameObject gOBJ;
    public void OnReticleEnter()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void OnReticleExit()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void OnReticleHover()
    {
        gOBJ.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not just targeting your functions from `OnPointerEnter` etc.? You have to make them public though.

Comment: well they are interfaces , why dont you call your functions from inside pointerEnter?

Comment: I have made functions public now. When I just renamed OnReticleEnter() to OnPointerEnter(), and defined Event Trigger's, pointer enter in the Inspector, the functions are not triggered.

Comment: @LumbusterTick Could you please tell me the syntax to use OnPointerEnter(), should I do so in the same script or another? Actually it is from raycast hit, the messages OnReticleEnter() is sent from camera to the object. I dont know how to make the OnReticleEnter() as OnPointerEnter(). Simply renaming it does not trigger the event in the Event Trigger.

Comment: @GunnarB. Actually the functions are produced from raycast hit send message script. When I send OnPointerEnter() as a message, it is not fired.

Comment: dude slow down , first tell me are you raycasting from the mouse? and what exactly are you trying to do ? Because using raycast eleminates the need to use pointerEnter as the raycast hit variable has all the information as to what it hit or when it stops hitting

Comment: @LumbusterTick: i hv a custom raycast script from camera that hits object from mouse position and sends message on hit OnRetcleEnter(). but the event trigger is not identifying pointer and doesnot fire any pointer enter events. thats why i m struck.

Comment: OnPointerEnter will not fire like that its not meant to , do u want to use the eventData inside PointerENter?

Comment: ok. any alternative so that i can access my function on Inspector to define multiple actions similar to Event Trigger?

Comment: ok simply use this :  public PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current); and do what ever you want with pointer data inside the OnRetcleEnter , hope this helps and u need to use using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the interfaces for the pointerEnter and PointerExit events in your class to be able to implement them. Your code might look something like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    // Custom reticle events
    public GameObject gOBJ;
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData){
        gOBJ.SetActive(true);
    }
   public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData){
        gOBJ.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is to call OnPointerEnter() when OnReticleEnter() is fired.